# search results highlighting with custom template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

my custom template tag to highlight query in search results.

```
def highlight(text, word):
    return mark_safe(text.replace(word, "<Strong>%s</Strong>" % word))
```

it's working, issue is
it is not ignoring case sensitive, 
I want to do it by using regular expression, have no idea weather mark_safe will support, didn't find any documentation are example in this scenario

```
word =search query

text =search result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub method in regular expressions which will find and replace given query(repl) in given string.

syntax:

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0);
```

code:

```
def highlight(text, word):
   word=word.lower()
   result=re.sub(word ,"<Strong>%s</Strong>" % word,text,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
   return mark_safe(result)
```